# Jmeter: Threads multiplied by loop count does not match number of samples

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running some tests in Jmeter with the following values - 
Number of Threads = 50
Number of Loop count = 133
I would expect the number of samples (column Count in the Summary report) to be 50*133=6650 but I see this as only 3220.

I tried this test with:
Number of Threads = 50
Number of Loop count = 100 and this time also I got the number of samples (Count) as 3221

I tried with:
Number of Threads = 30
Number of Loop count = 133 and this time also I got the number of samples (Count) as 3220

For some reason, Jmeter is limiting the max number of samples to a number around 3220. Why is this happening?

Regards
Ramesh

Comment: If this answer resolved your problem please mark it as answered.

Comment: Did you set duration limit?
If has there is the reason for number request is not round.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't have limitation on number of samples, if it is, it would be something like 2 billion.

Try the following:

1. Re-run your test [in non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
2. Open JMeter GUI. Don't open any .jmx file
3. Add [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) Listener
4. Click `Browse` button and open .jtl file which you specified by `-l` parameter in step 1
5. Check if real samples count matches your calculation.

It should be equal. If it isn't make sure that i.e. you are not using [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler which stops the test on certain condition or [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) with `Stop thread on EOF` set to true or whatever.

If the problem still persists and none of above recommendations help update the issue with your *jmeter.log* file

Comment: I don't use run but run tests with 1200 and 2500 users. The sample count with 1200 users is 1864885 and with 2500 users is 1723737. Given that Application throughput is also low with 2500 users I would guess that app can not handles these many users. But I was also hoping that number of samples would be higher with 2500 users than with 1200 users but that is not the case. I don' use Test Action, Stop thread on EOF etc.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have a similar issue. I am using Concurrency Thread Group with just one httprequest element.  When starting 7 threads with a ramp-up period of 7 seconds, in 7 steps I get 8389 samples. I would expect to get 1+2+3+4+5+6+7 samples.